# How to code a multiplicative ARIMA (non-consecutive lags)

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive-models

I'm working with weekly data and based on the form of a typical seasonal multiplicative ARIMA, I want to fit the following process to the time series:

y_t = phi* y_t-1 + PHI* y_t-52 + phi* PHI* y_t-53 + e_t

I basically want to obtain the coefficients phi, PHI, and the residuals (e's).

I am unaware of any packages or functions to do this and have been trying to use arima() while shutting off the MA and differencing components to keep it a restricted AR. But this isn't exactly capturing the process above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently there is a sarima function such that to get my desired (1,0,0)(1,0,0)_52 ARIMA I just use sarima(data,1,0,0,1,0,0,52)

Comment: Not sure about the difference is between sarima specification and arima(data,order=(1,0,0),seasonal = list(order=c(1,0,0),period=52))